# How can I access another field of a related ManyToMany table?

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm

Let's say I have the following models:

```
class Publication(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    publications = models.ManyToManyField(Publication)
    upload = models.ForeignKey(related_name='x1', Uploads)

class Uploads(models.Model):
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I want to select all the Articles of a specific upload topic along with their Publication *title*. So my output should be:

```
<QuerySet [
    {'id': 1, 'headline': 'headline1', 'publications': 'publication title 1'}, 
    {'id': 2, 'headline': 'headline2', 'publications': 'publication title 2'},
]
```

Currently I have this:

```py
(
    Article.objects.filter(upload__topic='sports')
    .values('id', 'headline', 'publications')
)
```

which gives me the following:

```
<QuerySet [
    {'id': 1, 'headline': 'headline1', 'publications': 1}, 
    {'id': 2, ''headline': 'headline2', 'publications': 2},
]
```

I know I can loop over the `QuerySet` and for each publication fire another DB query towards the `Publication` table to get the relevant title, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do that. Perhaps with a single query?

Comment: have you tried prefetch_related?

Comment: @VitAmin. No I haven't. Can you give an example?

Comment: @AminMir It doesn't work. Says that title is not a valid field

Comment: @daphtdazz Sorry, that was typo. I meant to write `Article`. Fixed it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask for the "publication title" of the articles you want, but you've got a many-to-many relation from article to publication, so (in general) there will be many "publication title"s for each article.

To get them all you can use `prefetch_related()` to traverse the many-to-many relationship. This will do a second query, but it is a pretty efficient way in general of doing it and allows django to provide all its standard ORM goodness.

```py
articles = (
    Article.objects
    .filter(upload__topic='sports')
    .prefetch_related('publications')
)
# Iterate over causes two database queries, 
# - one to select the relevant articles
# - second to select the publications for those articles. These
#   are cached in the related manager so...
for article in articles:
    # ...this should not perform another database query.
    # article.publications.all() is cached.
    print([pub.title for pub in article.publications.all()])
```

You wanted one queryset to get all the values in one go. You can do this, but you will get multiple entries for articles with multiple publications:

```py
# using articles from above
articles.values_list('headline', 'publications__title')
```

So if an article with headline "My Headline" has two publications with titles "Title 1" and "Title 2" you will get:

```py
[("My Headline", "Title 1"), ("My Headline", "Title 2")]
```

In my opinion you'd be best using the model instances returned by `articles` without using `values_list()`.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is a query which allows you to do this. First go into the shell by writing `python manage.py shell`. 
Then write this:
`

```
from appName.models import *
publications = Publication.objects.all()
first_pub = publications.first()
first_pub.article_set.all()
```

`
The app name should be the app where the model lives. line 2 is getting all the objects in your Publication model. line 3 is getting the first object (you can get what ever object you want). Line 4 is fetching all the articles from Article since it's related. the article part of article_set is the name of the model Article.

So using this idea you could display all the articles in a page by going to views.py and writing:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Publication


def index(request):
    publications = Publication.objects.all()

    return render(request, "home/index.html", {"publications": publications})
```

and in your html:

```
<body>
  {% for publication in publications %}
  {% for i in publication.article_set.all %}
  <h2>{{ i }}</h2>
  {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
</body>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Your answer, as is, fails here (`first_pub.article_set.all()`) because I have set a related name. If you change it to `first_pub.x1.all()` it's ok. However, even with this correction the rest of it doesn't answer my question. I want a specific output which I cannot get if I follow your answer.

Comment: Ok no problem. I don't think I can help you with finding a specific output. I hope you find the answer.